# Watching a rented iTunes movie on my iPad mini

Tags: itunes, ipad

I have the latest update on my iPad mini an I rented a movie from iTunes yesterday. It completed the download to my iPad but when I go to the iTunes Store and click on movies there is no rent tab. There is only purchase and it states no purchases....help!

Answer (score 1):

The rented tab is not in the iTunes Store. It is in the Videos app. If you downloaded it to your iPad successfully, there should be a rented tab in Videos. Otherwise, something went wrong, and you may need to contact iTunes support.